# What/who is "Bushell" the the Adam and the Ants song Press Darlings?

Tags: lyrics

```
If passion ends in fashion
Bushell is the best-dressed man in town
```

In an previous verse it goes *Nick Kent* is the best dressed guy in town. Nick Kent was a rock critic, but does anyone know what "Bushell" is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line refers to British newspaper columnist, rock music journalist, television presenter, author, musician and political activist Garry Bushell.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry_Bushell):

> His scathing reviews of the early punk incarnation of Adam and the Ants led to him being name-checked, along with veteran NME writer Nick Kent, in the band's song "Press Darlings".

From his own [web page](http://garry-bushell.co.uk/biography.htm#):

> One measure of Garry Bushell's impact was the number of songs written about him, including 'Press Darlings' by Adam Ant, 'Hurry Up Garry' by Crass, 'SingalongaBushell' by The Exploited, 'Garry Bushell's Band Of The Week' by the Notsensibles 'Sounds Like Sounds' by The Head and 'The Man Who Came In From The Beano' by the Angelic Upstarts